# Laravel queues pushing job into batch (and process it) when current job fails

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

Tried in many different ways but can't get this working, and i'm quite sure it was working until last framework updates (but got no clues diffing source code).

Basically: when a job on a site (A: StartTestJob) in a batch fails, after consuming its retries,
i want to push (and execute) another job (B) in the batch.
This latter just finds another site and push one new (A) job in the batch

Some additional infos : i have background workers (and they're constantly alive, i monitor with pgrep) and i use a package (https://github.com/mateusjunges/trackable-jobs-for-laravel) to track batches. database based queue. i always give `php artisan queue:restart` after code edits.

The job B gets properly pushed into batch but batch execution stops: all batch is marked as failed, with the job B just queued but not executed and.
execution halts there.

So when i launch command:

```
$server = Server::find($server_id);
$sites = $server->sites->all();
$max_simultaneous_procs = $server->simultaneous_procs;

$batchJobs = [];

$batch_reference_uuid = (string) Str::orderedUuid();
$sites = array_slice($sites, 0, $max_simultaneous_procs);

foreach ($sites as $site) {
  $chain_uuid = (string) Str::orderedUuid();
  $batchJobs [] = [new StartTestJob($site, $chain_uuid, $batch_reference_uuid)];
}

/**********************
// Dispatch batches
**********************/
$queue_name = 'procs_test_server_' . $server_id;
$batch_name = 'server-'. $server_id . ' : TestBatchSimultaneous' . ' ' . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$log_path = 'uuuuuu/storage/logs/jobs.log';

try {
    $batch = Bus::batch(
        $batchJobs
    )->then(...)->catch(...)->finally(...)
    ->onQueue($queue_name)->name($batch_name)->withOption("reference_uuid", $batch_reference_uuid)->dispatch();
    // ->allowFailures() makes no difference
}
```

queue halts with:

StartTestJob failed

FindNextSiteTestJob queued -and remains queued foreverer, as jobs processing halts-

Here the relevant code, sorry for long listing

```
class StartTestJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels, Batchable, ChainedTrackable {
        __construct as __baseConstruct;
    }
    public $site; public $chain_uuid; public $batch_reference_uuid;

    public function __construct(Site $site, string $chain_uuid, string $batch_reference_uuid)
    {
        $this->__baseConstruct($site, $chain_uuid, $batch_reference_uuid);
        $this->site = $site; $this->chain_uuid = $chain_uuid; $this->batch_reference_uuid = $batch_reference_uuid;
    }

    public function handle()
    {       
        // this is always empty, in this test
        $pingback_happened = Pingback::where(['chain_uuid' => $this->chain_uuid])->first();
        if(!$pingback_happened ){ $this->release(5); return; }
    }

    public function retryUntil(){ return now()->addSeconds(15);}

    public function failed($exception)
    {
        new FindNextSiteTestJob($this->site, $this->chain_uuid, $this->batch_reference_uuid);
    }
}
```

```
class FindNextSiteTestJob implements ShouldQueue, ShouldBeUnique
{
   use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels, Batchable, ChainedTrackable {
        __construct as __baseConstruct;
    }

    public $site; public $chain_uuid; public $batch_reference_uuid;

    public function __construct(Site $site, string $chain_uuid, string $batch_reference_uuid)
    {
        $this->__baseConstruct($site, $chain_uuid, $batch_reference_uuid);
        $this->site = $site; $this->chain_uuid = $chain_uuid; $this->batch_reference_uuid = $batch_reference_uuid;
    }

    public function handle()
    {

        $batch_reference_uuid = $this->batch_reference_uuid;

        // finds one site that still has to be processed
        $sites_done = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('tracked_jobs')->select('trackable_id')->where('batch_reference_uuid', $batch_reference_uuid)->groupBy('trackable_id')->get()->pluck('trackable_id')->toArray();
        $server = Server::find($this->site->server_id);
        $site_left = $server->sites->whereNotIn('id', $sites_done)->first();

        if($site_left){
            $site = $site_left;
            $chain_uuid = (string) Str::orderedUuid();
            $jobChain = [
                new StartTestJob($site, $chain_uuid, $batch_reference_uuid),
            ];
            $this->batch()->fresh()->add($jobChain);
            // even a gentle push with dispatch() doesnt'work:
            //$this->batch()->fresh()->add($jobChain)->dispatch();
        }
    }

    public function failed($exception){}
}
```